# Github showing an incorrect diff between main branch and PR branch

Tags: git, github

I am trying to figure out why the diff shown in the "compare files" does not actually reflect the changes I have been making. This seems to be a new problem in the last few days; I have used the "compare files" view MANY times before at work etc and it has always reflected the correct main branch, whereas now it has not.

Here is what is currently in my main branch (a test repo to figure out what the hell the problem is):

```js
// this is the entirety of main.js
function addition(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

And here is what I am merging into it:

```js
// this is the entirety of main.js
const difference = (num1, num2) => (
  num1 - num2
);
```

In my pull request, I would expect to see a merge conflict, since I am adding to the first few lines of my code. And I am getting the little bar that says "this branch has conflicts that must be resolved". However, when I look at the compare files view, this is what I see:

[image: there is no merge conflict]

The view does not recognize that in the main branch, there is clearly already a function there:

[image: the addition function is there]

I cannot come up with a reason why this might be so. Is it a hiccup with the "compare files" view? Could it possibly have something to do with the way that I have taken the branch off of main?

For me, this is not a huge deal; pulling / rebasing main into my current branch and handling the merge conflicts in my text editor is totally fine. I ask this because I am working with students who are new to git, and very new to group git in particular, and I would like to know why this unexpected behavior is happening so that I can explain it to them.

If you would like to check out the repo itself, [here it is](https://github.com/pmacaluso3/merge_conflicts).

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think conflicts ever show in that view, it just shows the changes from the new commits in the PR.

Comment: It should show them against the current version of the branch, though, right? I'm not making that up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloning that repository, then fetching the pull request:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/pmacaluso3/merge_conflicts
Cloning into 'merge_conflicts'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 18, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 1), reused 13 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), done.
$ cd merge_conficts
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/2/head:pr2
From https://github.com/pmacaluso3/merge_conflicts
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/2/head -> pr2
```

gets us ready to observe the commit graph.  Note that I have used the name `pr2` for my local branch to refer to your pull request #2, which is the one you find puzzling:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   7b4d901 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #3 from pmacaluso3/testing-merge-conflicts
|\  
| *   8941f5a (origin/testing-merge-conflicts) Merge branch 'main' into testing-merge-conflicts
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* |   5f144f2 Merge pull request #1 from pmacaluso3/pete/addition
|\ \  
| * | bffd4d1 addition!
|/ /  
| * 660b014 testing
|/  
| * 0bb0d7f (origin/j/difference, pr2) diff
|/  
* 0283a25 initial
```

So we see that the *commit* in my local `pr2` branch—which is also named `j/difference` in your repository, hence named `origin/h/difference` in mine, though I did not know that until I fetched `refs/pull/2/head` from GitHub—is commit `0bb0d7f`, which has, as its parent, commit `0283a25`.

If we look at what's in `0283a25`, we see that there are two *empty files:*

```
$ git show 0283a25 | sed 's/@/ /'
commit 0283a257e0e1802b57dcbbaccc7860a1b2de9dfa
Author: famousPete <pete.macaluso generalassemb.ly>
Date:   Wed Aug 26 13:37:10 2020 -0400

    initial

diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..45b983b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/README.md
 @ -0,0 +1 @@
+hi
diff --git a/main.js b/main.js
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

Hence, your PR does indeed tell Git to add three lines to an empty `main.js`.

This is what the view on GitHub shows as well.

> In my pull request, I would expect to see a merge conflict, since I am adding to the first few lines of my code.

The original proposed merge is of `0bb0d7f` with `0283a25`.  This merge is successful.  GitHub have done it and we can obtain it:

```
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/2/merge:temp
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From https://github.com/pmacaluso3/merge_conflicts
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/2/merge -> temp
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph temp
*   00e1eb0 (temp) Merge 0bb0d7f5b28f8817564f3acff0ca95a1622ea27d into 0283a257e0e1802b57dcbbaccc7860a1b2de9dfa
|\  
| * 0bb0d7f (origin/j/difference, pr2) diff
|/  
* 0283a25 initial
```

> And I am getting the little bar that says "this branch has conflicts that must be resolved".

If you merge *now*, to `main`, then yes, there would be a merge conflict.  But until someone rebases this particular commit *on* (the tip of) `main`, that merge conflict is left to whoever might try to merge this commit to `main`.  It would be nice if GitHub could do a diff against the current tip of `main` instead of just against the merge base it chose earlier.

Comment: Does this suggest this occurs because the PR was created before GitHub knew about the change to the file on branch main? If yes, is there not a "refresh" or "restart merge" option?

Comment: I think it does (imply that the PR occurred when the tip of `main` was at that point) since GitHub will have to do the resolution of a branch name to a commit hash themselves. But there's no such button on GitHub, at least, not that I have ever seen.

Comment: I don't use GitHub much (mostly Azure Devops lately), but wow, that's really surprising. I suppose then you'd have to close and reopen the PR to update it. Or maybe switch target branches and then back to the desired one. I hope either of those would force a refresh.

Comment: @TTT closing & reopening does not refresh unfortunately. neither does switching te branch there & back again. i suppose its because the temp `00e1eb0` commit still exists and there's no reason that gh sees to update it when it's still there

Comment: @torek thank you! this makes a lot of sense. i typically rebase by default so i hadn't come up against this in a while, thought I was going completely nuts lol. this explanation was very clear! i appreciate it very much.

Comment: This actually relates to one of my big gripes with GitHub: they *hide the commit graph* (I think this is on purpose, to make people think Git is simpler than it actually is), which means you can't see why things like this occurred. You have to get the commits locally and look.

Comment: While this is all good information (and I agree that Github not having a graph view is bizarre and annoying), I'm not sure it actually describes what's happening on Github. I think it's really much simpler - Github never shows conflicts on that screen.

Comment: @TTT I don't think it's anything to do with when the PR was opened; that view only ever shows the changes you've committed, not the result of applying the merge.

Comment: @IMSoP - That makes sense. I'm not that familiar with GitHub (been using Azure Devops mostly). So in a PR, how do you see the changes you are making as a result of the PR? I expect something like this for each file: Left side: current main branch, right side: what will be in main branch after you complete the PR.

Comment: @TTT I have the opposite problem: I've not used much other than Github. What does a conflict look like in a view like that (what I called "option 1" in my answer)? Does it show both versions of the lines being added next to each other? Or does it switch to a three-way view? That _actual_ result after you complete the PR will be whatever you choose to do with the conflict, but the UI can't know that yet.

Comment: @IMSoP in Azure Devops it tells you there are conflicts that you should resolve outside of the tool. But the PR does show you the before (current version) and after (if you complete the PR) of every file for the target branch. I'm not sure how you could accurately approve a PR that doesn't include the target branch HEAD version of each file. (It seems like in GitHub you can review the changes against the branched commit, that's fine, but you can't confidently say go ahead and merge it?)

Comment: @TTT If there are conflicts, there is no "after (if you complete the PR)" because you can't "complete" the PR without resolving them. Are you saying Azure Devops just hides the diff view until you resolve the conflicts? Or does it combine a view of the conflict into the diff somehow? I can see either of those working if it's an _extra_ diff, but being very user-unfriendly if it's the _only_ way to review the proposed changes. As for the possible reasoning for Github's choice, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that the view you're looking at in Github doesn't show what you think it shows.

When you have made commits on two branches (I'll call them `main` and `feature`), you have a commit graph looking something like this:

```
            d -- e -- f   <- main
           /
a -- b -- c
           \
            g -- h -- i   <- feature
```

When you propose to merge `feature` into `main`, what you are aiming to end up with is this:

```
            d -- e -- f
           /           \
a -- b -- c             j  <- main   
           \           /
            g -- h -- i
```

Note that `main` and `feature` are pointers to *commits*, and do not "own" any changes; and each commit contains a snapshot of the entire repository at a point in time.

In order to create a two-way diff, we need to pick two of these snapshots to compare; there are several such comparisons we could view for this proposed merge:

1. `main` before and after the merge: compare `f` with a proposed version of `j`
2. `main` and `feature` before the merge: compare `f` directly with `i`
3. the changes that are in `feature` that aren't already in `main`: compare `c` (the last commit reachable from both branches) with `i`
4. the changes that are in `main` that aren't already in `feature`: compare `c` with `f`

You have assumed that Github will show you option 1. Since the merge creates conflicts, the proposed version of `j` would have to include some representation of these, as though you'd created a commit where you didn't resolve them.

What Github is actually showing you is option 3: regardless of what's happened on `main`, it only shows *the changes that were made on `feature`*. You can see this most clearly when you have more than one commit on `feature`: it will allow you to filter the view to individual commits, which wouldn't make much sense if it was comparing to a proposed merge commit `j`.

There are a few reasons they might have chosen this way:

- Historically, a "pull request" was a series of patches sent by e-mail. The person sending the e-mail didn't know what the recipient's `main` branch looked like.
- When reviewing a change, you can add inline comments against particular line numbers. If line 100 became line 150 because a non-conflicting change to `main` added 50 lines further up the file, the comment's new location would have to be calculated.
- If there is a conflict, as in this case, a proposed version of commit `j` would have to include some kind of markup for those conflicts. Just viewing that as a two-way diff would result in confusing annotations, e.g. that you were adding the code `<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<`. A more customised UI would be possible, but tricky to design so that it's easy to understand.

Some UIs will allow you to visually resolve conflicts in a three-pane view, which is actually cramming in a lot of information: the outer panels show comparisons 3 and 4 above (the changes made on each of the two branches), while the centre panel shows comparison 1 (the current attempt to merge them). An important thing about these views is that the centre panel is interactive - it shows the result of you *resolving* the conflicts, not just a textual representation of them.